# Increment number of Consecutive Occurrence of values in Table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following data in a MariaDB database("with" clause is not supported):

```
visitor_id,  this_month,  this_month_access,  last_month,  last_month_access,  monthly_status<br>
1,  201901,  access,  null,  null,  new_ visitor<br>
1,  201902,  null,  201901,  access,  unretained_ visitor<br>
1,  201903,  null,  null,  null,  dormant<br>
1,  201904,  null,  null,  null,  dormant<br>
1,  201905,  access,  null,  null,  reaccquired<br>
1,  201906,  access,  201905,  access,  existed_ visitor<br>
1,  201907,  null,  201906,  access,  unretained_ visitor<br>
1,  201908,  null,  null,  null,  dormant<br>
1,  201909,  access,  null,  null,  reaccquired<br>
```

What I am trying to do is to add a new column, "dormant_length", and its value is increment based on the column "monthly_status", ie., if "monthly_status" is dormant, it will increment continuously. The result is as below:

```
visitor_id,  this_month,  this_month_access,  last_month,  last_month_access,  monthly_status,  dormant_length<br>
1,  201901,  access,  null,  null,  new_ visitor,  <br>
1,  201902,  null,  201901,  access,  unretained_ visitor,  <br>
1,  201903,  null,  null,  null,  dormant,  1<br>
1,  201904,  null,  null,  null,  dormant,  2<br>
1,  201905,  access,  null,  null,  reaccquired,  <br>
1,  201906,  access,  201905,  access,  existed_ visitor,  <br>
1,  201907,  null,  201906,  access,  unretained_ visitor,  <br>
1,  201908,  null,  null,  null,  dormant,  1<br>
1,  201909,  access,  null,  null,  reaccquired,  <br>
```

I apology for the ugly format and I failed to insert image here.

I tried row_number() function but could not work it out. Very appreciate your help!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Failing to insert an image was a good thing

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` but you need to identify the groups.  In this case, the groups can be determined by the number of non-dormant values before each row.  So:

```
select t.*,
       (case when status = 'dormant'
             then row_number() over (partition by visitor_id, grp, status order by this_month)
        end) as dormant_length
from (select t.*,
             sum(monthly_status <> 'dormant') over (partition by visitor_id order by this_month) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=db356348bdd7f341e5b89967ef19fd29) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hey Gordon, thanks for help!  
Running the query, the result seems not what I expected. The dormant_length should be rolling count of the number of months since they most recent access.  
In your result, the column "dormant_length" is always 1.  However its value of month "201904" should be 2 rather than 1.  
Any thoughts?

Comment: @David . . . Arrgggg.  The `count()` is now `sum()` which was always my intention.

Comment: Great, it works well. I accept this as the best answer. Thanks Gordon!